How to set the language for custom labels in an LWC component embedded in a Visualforce page?
I'm working with a Visualforce page in a Force.com site, and I have embedded a Lightning Web Component (LWC) inside the page. I want both the Visualforce page and the LWC component to display the values of custom labels according to the browser's default language.
I know that for the Visualforce page, I can set the language using the language attribute in the <apex:page> tag. However, the custom labels in the LWC component are not being translated, even when the language attribute of the apex:page tag is set. On the other hand, the same custom labels within the Visualforce page HTML are correctly translated.
How can I ensure that the custom labels in the embedded LWC component are also displayed in the current browser language?
